# Handle Parse push notifications while app is not running (Android)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Parse Version: 1.9.2

When I send a push notification from my Parse dashboard and the app is not running I receive the following dialog error:

"Unfortunately 'app name' has stopped."

Notifications work while the app is running, but obviously the vast majority of the utility of a push notification is to receive one when it is not.

I've followed each of the integration tutorials to a tee: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.elgami.customizer"
    android:versionCode="23"
    android:versionName="2.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.elgami.customizer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.elgami.customizer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.elgami.application.GlobalApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Google Analytics Version v4 needs this value for easy tracking -->
        <!--
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
        -->

        <!--
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.elgami.customizer.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".IntroActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PurchaseActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.elgami.gallery.GalleryActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ProfileSharingConsentActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.elgami.utility.ElgamiContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.elgami"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentProcessingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_processing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WebWrapper"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.elgami.utility.WrapperWeb"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wrapper_web" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <!-- Custom Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.elgami.customizer.Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- End Custom Receiver -->

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.elgami.customizer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Java class in which my Parse is initialized. What could be going on?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Parse.initialize(this, "myAppID", "myClientID");

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

logcat:

```
06-11 23:44:02.880  12738-12738/com.elgami.customizer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elgami.customizer, PID: 12738
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.parse.PushService@39ffceb5 with Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.elgami.customizer cmp=com.elgami.customizer/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2911)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
            at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:448)
            at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:267)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:324)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getIntentReceivers(ManifestInfo.java:132)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.hasIntentReceiver(ManifestInfo.java:124)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushUsesBroadcastReceivers(ManifestInfo.java:176)
            at com.parse.PushService.wipeRoutingAndUpgradePushStateIfNeeded(PushService.java:504)
            at com.parse.PushService.onStartCommand(PushService.java:485)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2894)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: check answer I have posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must initialise the all `Parse` intialization in `Application` class as

```
public class GlobalApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this, "myAppID", "myClientID");

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

see this link for [custom Application class](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)

Comment: Amazing! This worked precisely. The problem was that I was initializing Parse in one of my Activities instead of a custom application. I wish I had more reputation so that I could give you some votes!

Comment: Okay I just did. Thanks.